# Android: 2 tasks one after the other with time difference

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am working on AudioRecord.

The requirement is I have to generate a tone and play the tone for 0.25 seconds. After that the audio recording should be automatically started and continue for 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, the audio recording should be stopped.

I wrote the code to generate tone and to record and play the audio.

But I could not sequence it with the required timing. I am facing thread issue because of the RecordThread: overflow or java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().

```
genTone(Constants.HEART_TONE_FREQ);
playToneInPhone();

Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        isRecording=true;
        recordingTimer = new RecordingTimer(10000,1000);
        recordingTimer.start();
        startRecording();
    }
});
try {
    recordThread.sleep(250);
    recordThread.start();
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {

}
```

RecordingTimer is a CountDownTimer. Can someone help me out resolving this issue?

Comment: Try to initialize recordingTimer outside run() method.   [...]`playToneInPhone();
recordingTimer = new RecordingTimer(10000,1000);
Thread recordThread = new [...]`

Comment: Nope. That cannot be correct. Because I need to start the recording timer only after the playTone finishes. Anyhow I fixed the issue. Below is my code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the above issue by puttin recordingTimer after the thread start. Please let me know if there is any other better way of doing this.

```
genTone(Constants.HEART_TONE_FREQ);
    playToneInPhone();

    Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRecording=true;

            startRecording();
        }
    });
    try {
        recordThread.sleep(250);
        recordThread.start();
        recordingTimer = new RecordingTimer(10000,1000);
        recordingTimer.start();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) with [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) function for this purpose. It will run on the main UI thread, so synchronization will be forced.

I can whip up some sample implementation, if that would help? : )

Comment: I already tried that one. The issue is I have to time the Recording as well. I could not use handler within handler.

Comment: No, but you can interrupt it. Isn't that what you want to do -- have a 0.25s timer and a 10s one?

Comment: yes.. the tone should be 0.25 following that audio record should be automatically started and finished after 10 s

Comment: Wait, why not implement a callback at the end of the tone? Or am I being silly and misunderstanding the point completely? : P

Comment: Something like: `{0.25sTone(); 10sRecording();}`

Comment: That's what you're doing and getting an error, aren't you? :D If the runnables are timed at 0.25s and 10s, you can surely call them one after the other? I remember doing this before for a self calling function.

Answer (score 0):

ScheduledExecutorSrvice should be used (with delayed or scheduled streaming) or  Future Interface that retrieves objects after streaming completed (resulting data would be received).  it is sent via the streamed object instead of Runnable interface